# Align Members in a ListBox – get correct number of needed TABs

Tags: c#

I am currently still using a ListBox. In this, all products are displayed one below the other. For each individual product, properties are separated with tab characters. I would like to align the properties sensibly, but only look at the `BrandName` for now. Therefore, I get the length of the longest brand name and check for each individual name how many characters I must bridge and fill these gaps with tabs.

I think I've already built a sufficient function here, but I think you guys can do better.

Yes, I know a `DataGridView` is better compared to a `ListBox`, but my point today is to make it look reasonable for now.

The font is Segoe UI, font size is 12. I couldn't figure out the right `TabWidth` unfortunately – I've seen questions on Stack Overflow where they tried to use a comma number, based on “average width of a char” (I guess that's only valid for the English language).

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019; version 16.11.11.
WinForms application (.NET Framework 4.8) with C#.

```
private void update_ListBox()
        {
            ListBoxEx1.Items.Clear();
            //ListBoxEx1.Items.AddRange(AllEntries.Select(x => $"{x.product.BrandName}{"\t"}{x.product.ModelName}{"\t"}{x.CreationTime.ToString("d", Deu)}{"\t"}{x.product.DescriptionOrNotes}{"\t"}{Math.Round(x.product.SellingPrice, 2)} €").ToArray());
            int Max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < AllEntries.Count; i++)
            {
                if (AllEntries[i].product.BrandName.Length > Max)
                {
                    Max = AllEntries[i].product.BrandName.Length;
                }
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i < AllEntries.Count; i++)
            {
                ListBoxEx1.Items.Add(ToStringForListbox(Max,
                                                        AllEntries[i].product.BrandName,
                                                        AllEntries[i].product.ModelName,
                                                        AllEntries[i].CreationTime,
                                                        AllEntries[i].product.DescriptionOrNotes,
                                                        AllEntries[i].product.SellingPrice));
            }
        }

        private string ToStringForListbox(int Maximum_length,
                                          string BrandName,
                                          string ModelName,
                                          DateTime CreationTime,
                                          string DescriptionOrNotes,
                                          decimal SellingPrice)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BrandName))
            {
                string MultiTab;
                // zu überbrückende Länge
                int Length_to_be_overridden = Maximum_length - BrandName.Length;
                int TabWidth = 10;

                int how_many_Tabs = Length_to_be_overridden / TabWidth;

                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("\t");

                for (int i = 0; i < how_many_Tabs; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append("\t");
                }
                MultiTab = sb.ToString();

                return $"{BrandName}{MultiTab}{ModelName}{"\t"}{CreationTime.ToString("d", Deu)}{"\t"}{DescriptionOrNotes}{"\t"}{Math.Round(SellingPrice, 2)} €";
            }
            else
            {
                //              Macron ¯
                return $"{Convert.ToChar(0xAF)}{"\t"}{ModelName}{"\t"}{CreationTime.ToString("d", Deu)}{"\t"}{DescriptionOrNotes}{"\t"}{Math.Round(SellingPrice, 2)} €";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [naming guidelines for .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) should be used to name things, because reading and understanding code which follows such guidelines is much easier for other developers.

For .NET:

- methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing
- method arguments should be named using `camelCase` casing
- local and class variables/fields should be named using `camelCase` casing
- `snake_case` casing **should't** be used

---

`ToStringForListbox()`

Returning early by changing the `if` condition will save you one level of indentation, which makes your code more readable.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(BrandName))
{
    //              Macron ¯
    return $"{Convert.ToChar(0xAF)}{"\t"}{ModelName}{"\t"}{CreationTime.ToString("d", Deu)}{"\t"}{DescriptionOrNotes}{"\t"}{Math.Round(SellingPrice, 2)} €";
}

string MultiTab;
// zu überbrückende Länge
...

return $"{BrandName}{MultiTab}{ModelName}{"\t"}{CreationTime.ToString("d", Deu)}{"\t"}{DescriptionOrNotes}{"\t"}{Math.Round(SellingPrice, 2)} €";
```

Comments should be used to tell **why** something is done in the way it is done. **What** is done should be told by the code itself by using meaningful names for naming things. In addition in software-development it is common to use english for comments as well.

This

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("\t");

for (int i = 0; i < how_many_Tabs; i++)
{
    sb.Append("\t");
}
MultiTab = sb.ToString();
```

can be simplified by using the [overloaded constructor of the `string` class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-string-ctor(system-char-system-int32)) like so

```
MultiTab = new string('\t', how_many_Tabs + 1);
```

Instead of passing 6 arguments to the method it would be more readable to just pass `Maximum_length` and an item of whatever type `AllEntries[i]` is.

---

`update_ListBox()`

Like already mentioned, naming things is important. You should be able to grasp at first glance what something is about. Looking at `ListBoxEx1` **Sam the maintainter** whould need to guess what this is. Sure a `ListBox` but what will it contain? **Sam the maintainer**  would need to read more code only to check what and how it is used. Are there more `ListBoxEx`s because of the `1`? Such stuff makes finding bugs hard and should be avoided.

Finding the `Max` of the `BrandName.Length` can be simplified by using some linq-magic like so

```
int Max = AllEntries.Max(entry => entry.product.BrandName.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, especially the `overloaded constructor of the string class` didn't occur to me.

I should look more into LINQ, then I don't always have to use for loops. 

You are right about `ListBoxEx` – it is unnecessary to call it `ListBoxEx1`.